# Bulma with Angular11 text not changing, but background does

Tags: css, angular11

I have the following Text section and style class
The background color is changing, but the "title is-1 has-text-centered" has no effect,
nor the h1.title.  it throws and error

```
<section class="heading-section">
    <h1 class="title is-1 has-text-centered">Todos</h1>
</section>


.heading-section {
    background:linear-gradient(to right, rgb(2,228,171), rgb(74,215,240));
   
    padding: 100px;

    h1.title {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: white;
        text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(black, 0.12);
    }
}
```

Angular.js has the following

```
 "styles": [
          "../node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css", 
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
```

Style.css is importing it

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import "../node_modules/bulma/bulma.sass"
```

Comment: try ```!important``` may be some other selector is overriding the value

Comment: doesn't seem to like it.  I put it after the styles, in the CSS and angular.js file.  nothing seemed to work with it.  not sure if this stylesheet works only with certain browsers, I am working with chrome

Comment: ????? what are you talking about ??????? which stylesheet? sass? sass is compiled to css before working with the browser

Comment: i tried to put it in several places here    h1.title {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: white;
        text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(black, 0.12);
    }  then here  "styles": [
          "../node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css", 
          "src/styles.scss"
        ], (angular js)   Sorry I really don't fully understand angular yet.  just learning

Comment: for the h2.title, I tried to put it after the h1.title, then after the font-weight:bold;

Comment: You have to put it after the value like this ```h1.title { color: white !important; }```

Comment: In vsCode, I am still getting no results and a error between h1 and title,on the "." 
 .heading-section {
    background:linear-gradient(to right, rgb(2,228,171), rgb(74,215,240));
   
    padding: 100px;

    h1.title  {
        font-weight: bold !important;
        color: white !important;
        text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(black, 0.12) !important;
    }
}

Comment: I appreciate the help

Comment: I was expressing my gratitude, but I still have issues.  the problem is showing between the h1 and title on the "."  I did add the !important after each line.  no hlep

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/dO3iCeA.png It is working fine I copied the code and pasted in VScode

Comment: If its still not working add the selector for rest of the classes on the h1 as well like this: ```h1.title.is-1.has-text-centered```

Comment: I must be missing another package, my h1 is not the same color as my heading-section it's white. I will try to figure that out, might solve the whole thing

Comment: may be..........